# Improve sqlite query Where field in to exists

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-sql

Here's my simplified working query:

```
select fields, sum(otherFields)
from table1
where table1.field1 in (Select table2.field1 
                        from table2
                        where table1.id=table2.id 
                        order by table2.date desc limit 100)
group by fields
```

As you can see, I need from `table1` only the rows that are in `table2` but these ones filtered by last newer 100.

The query takes a bit too long, so I've tried to replace the `in` with `exists`

```
 select fields, sum(otherFields)
    from table1
    where exists (Select table2.field1 
                   from table 2
                   where table1.id=table2.id 
                     and table1.field=table2.fields
                   order by table2.date desc limit 100)
    group by fields
```

While this would work for queries that don't use limit in my case it does not work properly.

So, how can I properly filter the result from table1 in relation with only a limited number of rows from table2?

Comment: I guess you could work with a join between both tables, it seems more natural to me. I do not know whether this imporves your query time though, did you test this?

Comment: @MarcelP I had the impression that I need a RIGHT jong with the table 2 select, but it seems that RIGHT join is not supported by sqlite

Comment: Show the database schema (including any indexes).